# How can I play the Chemical Revolution mission?

Tags: assassins-creed-unity

So I have bought the season pass for AC Unity, yet I've not found how to play the Chemical Revolution mission which is included as part of the season pass.

How can I play this mission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mission can be found in the **Luxembourg District**

Semi-Near the Restricted area as I marked on this map with an X

[image: the map is just to mark with an X]

and **it is considered to be a Paris Stories Mission**.

> **The mission won't have any special symbol, it will have the regular Assassin's Crest Icon from the other Paris Stories Missions.**

If you want to see someone play the mission watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdGe4UtkkxI). It even shows where to go precisely.

Answer (score -1):

Check the [ACU Companion](http://blog.ubi.com/assassins-creed-unity-companion-app-faq/) App to find the exact location on the map.